# Automation of file uploading Facebook

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I'm trying to automate file uploading to Facebook dialogs, using Selenium, python and chrome webdriver. Here is code:

```
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/1231231242314")
    js = "document.querySelectorAll('input[type=\"file\"]')[0].setAttribute('class', '')"
    driver.execute_script(js)
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='file']")[0].send_keys("d:\local.jpg")
    js = "document.querySelectorAll('input[type=\"file\"]')[0].parentNode.parentNode.submit()"
    driver.execute_script(js)
```

I'm delete classes of element that it's accessible to  send_keys() method.Then send_keys() set value of input element to "d:\local.jpg", it works. But when form submit happens nothing, just a redirect to https: //upload.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/upload.php. How can the file be uploaded?

P.S. Sorry for bad English.